# Make adapting div by bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bootstrap and ruby on rails amateur. I want a adapting "div". My code looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    [if true]
    <div class="span2">
      div1
    </div>
    [endif]

    <div class="span10">
     div2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want **div2** (span10) can adapting, means:

```
if "true", **div1** == 20% && **div2** == 80%
if "not true", **div1** cannot be show, then the width of dev2 will be 100%.
```

I've tried `span10`, I found the width of it always `82.906%`.
How can I do that?

---

My environment:

- Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails: gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
- Bootstrap: gem "bootstrap-sass", "~>
  2.3.2.2"

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My soluction:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    [unless CONDITION]
    <div class="span2">
      div1
    </div>
    [endif]

    <div class="<%= CONDITION? ? "span12" : "span10" %>">
     div2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, I've written the function in **helper**, and return a **flag** (true or false). I can call the this function and get the ture or false to decide which class (span10 or span12) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  [if true]
  <div class="span2">
   div1
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
  [else]
  <div class="span12">
  [endif]
   div2
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My soluction almost like yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in your style by using preprocessors like [SAS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)